# 2000 Corolla, CV axles disconnect and reconnect when stopping/turning

Tags: toyota, corolla, cv-joint

Car is 2000 Corolla with 58k miles. My front left CV axle was leaking last year so I decided to replace both front CV axles with some generic brand. This was about 5000 miles ago and it worked great for about a year. Before replacing the CV axles, this issue mentioned below never occurred. I also drained and filled with Royal Purple ATF when the CV axles were changed.

The issue is that sometimes, when making slow sharp turns and then immediately coming to a stop, sometimes the CV axles gets "stuck". If I let go of the brakes at the stop...the car rolls backwards (it feels like something is loose and the wheels "freeroll")! During this time, the engine is at 900-1000rpm (it should be 650 at idle). It's like the CV axles get disconnected from the transmission.Then, if I press down the gas pedal a little bit...the engine hits around 1400rpm and the CV axles "connect" again and there is a slight jolt and everything is alright.

This also happens at sudden stops (braking hard). Also a related issue: When making a quick sharp turn at normal speed, as soon as the steering wheel comes back to the center...the engine immediately hits 2300 rpm and then comes back down to 1600rpm. Its like the CV axles are disconnecting (transmission is still engaged and computer detects loss of power and raises engine rpm) and then reconnecting (computer detects power to the wheels are restored...and the engine rpm drops to normal levels).

Other than that, the transmission fluid is normal and it shifts fine.

Do you think the Royal purple ATF could be causing the issue (after working fine for a year)? Maybe a transmission solenoid?

Comment: This sounds like more of a transmission problem, than a problem with your CV joints/axles. The thing which gets me is you only have 58k on this car and you've already replaced the CV joints/axles? They should have been good out to about 125k, at least.

Comment: The left CV axle was leaking, I decided to replace both of them. My work commute has a lot of construction zones so probably something hit the boot and caused the leak.

Comment: Sounds reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

This is kindof old but

This issue sounds like a transmission issue. Most likely due to standard wear. Since this happens during hard braking or turning I suspect some fluid might be pushing against something or something is loose. This can be due to low transmission fluid. If it is low on fluid and it sloshes away from the pickup tube it can lead to low oil pressure which can disengage the bands effectively setting the trans in neutral. This can be exacerbated by worn out transmission parts. It could also be leaking out a bad seal.

I would have asked xmlapi if the trans fluid level was checked.